# Get entire row as array of String from a TreeItem with multiple columns

Tags: java, menu, tree, swt

I have an org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer and each item has 2 columns.

```
TreeViewer myTreeViewer = new TreeViewer(myComposite);
Tree myTree= myTreeViewer.getTree();
myTreeViewer.setContentProvider(new TreeContentProvider());
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
// initializing headers
}
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
   TreeItem item = new TreeItem(myTree, SWT.NONE);
   item.setData(new String[]{"Item " + i, i%2==0? "active" : "inactive"};
   // of course, the item has children, but they are not relevant in this question
}
```

Now, I want for each item to add an event for right click - opens a popup menu with text "Activate Item":

```
final Menu myMenu = new Menu(myTree);
myTree.setMenu(myMenu);
myMenu.addMenuListener(new MenuAdapter()
{
   public void menuShown(MenuEvent e) {            
      MenuItem[] menuItems = myMenu.getItems();
      for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
         menuItems[i].dispose();
      }
      TreeItem treeItem = myTree.getSelection()[0];
      MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem(myMenu, SWT.NONE);

      // Here I want to do some improvements
      newItem.setText("Activate " + myTree.getSelection()[0].getText());
   }
 }
 });
```

In this moment, if I do a right click on an item, it is opened a popup menu with text "Activate Item ".
The problem is if I select an item, it is selected only the first cell (not entire row). What I want to do is to check if the Item is "active" or "inactive" (value of column 2 of tree item). And if it is "active", I want to set the text "Deactivate". Variable myTree.getSelection()[0] contains only the text from column 1.

Comment: If you use `TreeViewer` you should not be adding to the tree using `TreeItem` - the viewer is control of the tree and gets the items from the content provider when you call `setInput`. Just use `Tree` if you want to use TreeItems

Comment: In my project I must use TreeViewer, because it is used also a custom framework which uses classes from swt and jface. So I need to find another way to implement.

Comment: So you must not use TreeItem. The TreeViewer creates the TreeItems internally. The content provider and label provider work together to show the content. You use the TreeViewer `getStructuredSelection` to get the selection. The objects the content provider returns can contain everything you need.